# How do I add a new google contact on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, mail.app, contacts, google-sync

I’m trying to add a new contact on an iPhone to a google account. I can go to contacts.google.com in safari and add it there, but is there a way to do that with the contacts app? I have google contacts synced in mail accounts settings. I’m not sure where my contacts are actually being saved, is it iCloud?

Comment: There's several questions & answers on this site for syncing google contacts to your iPhone.  Did you try any of those solutions?  If you did, what problems did you encounter?

Comment: I’m okay with syncing google contacts to my iPhone, what I’m not sure how sync from the iPhone to google. I guess I’m looking for bidirectional sync, but I’m not sure what the right terms are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already enabled the toggle for your Google account to sync contacts, you only need to set your *Default Account* in your iOS Contacts settings to be your Google Account. Then, when adding contacts they will automatically be uploaded to your Google Account.

Source: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/sync-iphone-contacts-to-gmail/